# Group and count total of blanks and total of rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have the following dataframe

```
  Country   Name  Code Signed  Index
0      CZ  Paulo     3      x   1
1      AE  Paulo   Yes   None   1
2      AE  Paulo   Yes   None   2
3      AE  Paulo     1    Yes   5
4      CZ  Paulo  None   None   6
5      DK  Paulo   Yes   None   9
6      DK  Paulo  None   None   20
7      PT  Paulo     2    Yes   20
8      PT  Paulo     1    Yes   22
```

I need three new columns after grouping by `country`

1. count the missing values in `Code` and `Signed` column
2. total of rows that have both values filled
3. total of rows that have the same Country value
4. point the rows where we have any of those values blank per Country (list or non list format) using the column "Index" as reference

If any of the Countries have all their `Code` and `Signed` rows filled, remove it from the dataframe.

In this case, it would return this dataframe:

```
  Country  Total_Blanks_on_Code  Total_Blanks_on_Signed Total_of_rows_with_both_values_filled  Total_of_rows_of_the_Country  Rows with any blank
0      CZ                     1                       1                                  None                             2                    6
1      AE                     2                       0                                     1                             3                   [1,2]
2      DK                     2                       1                                  None                             2                   [9,20]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
df['both_filled'] = (df.Code.notna() & df.Signed.notna()).map({True:True, False:None})
df['Rows_with_any_blank'] = df.Index[df['both_filled'].isna()]
gb = df.groupby('Country', sort=False)
df2 = ( gb.count().assign(
    Rows_with_any_blank=gb['Rows_with_any_blank']
    .agg(lambda x: list(x.dropna().astype(int)))) )
df2 = ( df2.assign(
    Total_Blanks_on_Code=df2.Name - df2.Code,
    Total_Blanks_on_Signed=df2.Name - df2.Signed)
    [df2.both_filled < df2.Name]
    [['Total_Blanks_on_Code','Total_Blanks_on_Signed',
        'both_filled','Name','Rows_with_any_blank']]
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={
        'Name':'Total_of_rows_of_the_Country', 
        'both_filled':'Total_of_rows_with_both_values_filled'
    }) )
```

Input:

```
  Country   Name  Code Signed  Index
0      CZ  Paulo     3      x      1
1      AE  Paulo   Yes   None      1
2      AE  Paulo   Yes   None      2
3      AE  Paulo     1    Yes      5
4      CZ  Paulo  None   None      6
5      DK  Paulo   Yes   None      9
6      DK  Paulo  None   None     20
7      PT  Paulo     2    Yes     20
8      PT  Paulo     1    Yes     22
```

Output:

```
  Country  Total_Blanks_on_Code  Total_Blanks_on_Signed  Total_of_rows_with_both_values_filled  Total_of_rows_of_the_Country Rows_with_any_blank
0      CZ                     1                       1                                      1                             2                 [6]
1      AE                     0                       2                                      1                             3              [1, 2]
2      DK                     1                       2                                      0                             2             [9, 20]
```

Explanation:

- Create `both_filled` column which is `True` if both `Code` and `Signed` are non-null and is `None` otherwise (this allows us to later use `count()` to effectively sum the number of rows having both columns non-null)
- Create `Rows_with_any_blank` column which contains the value in `Index` for rows where neither of `Code` and `Signed` is null
- Create a `groubpy` object `gb` by `Country`
- Use `count()` to get the number of non-null entries per group in each column of `gb`
- Use `assign()` to overwrite the `Rows_with_any_blank` column to be a list of the non-null `Index` values for each group
- Use `assign()` to create and populate columns `Total_Blanks_on_Code` and `Total_Blanks_on_Signed`
- Keep only rows where the count in `both_filled` < the count in `Name` (which is the total number of rows in the original df); this removes any `Country` for which all `Code` and `Signed` rows are filled
- Select the 5 desired columns in the specified order using `[[]]`
- Use `reset_index()` to switch `Country` from the index to a column
- Use `rename()` to change `Name` and `both_filled` to have the specified labels `Total_of_rows_of_the_Country` and `Total_of_rows_with_both_values_filled`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the definitions/conditions you gave, the country AE should have a total blanks on Code equal to 0 and not 2.

Anyway, you can use the code below to get the format of output you're looking for :

```
out = (df.assign(Total1 = df['Code'].isna(),
                 Total2 = df['Signed?'].isna(),
                 Total3 = ~df['Code'].isna() & ~df['Signed?'].isna())
        .groupby('Country', as_index=False)
        .agg(NumberOfCountries = ('Country','size'),
             Total1 = ('Total1','sum'),
             Total2 = ('Total2','sum'),
             Total3 = ('Total3','sum'))
        ).rename(columns={'Total1': 'Total Blanks on Code', 'Total2': 'Total Blanks on Signed?', 
                    'Total3': 'Total of rows with both values filled', 'NumberOfCountries': 'Total of rows of the Country'})
```

##### >>> `print(out)` :

[image]

Comment: sorry just corrected the question with an extra column needed. Thanks a lot!